# Quick question on marginal density function

Tags: calculus, probability, density-function

Question is:

> $f(x,y)=e^{(-x/y)}e^{-y}/y$ *when* $x>0, y>0$ 
>   *it equals to 0*,  *otherwise*
>
> What is $f_{X}(x)?$

I think:
$f_{X}(x)= \int^{∞}_0f(x,y)dy = \int^{∞}_0 e^{(-x/y)}e^{-y}/y dy$

Then I should 
consider *y* as a variable,

*x* as constant.

but it seems I can't separate x, y. Since the term is

$ e^{[-(x+y^2)/y]} /y dy$

if we consider

$ (e^z)' = e^z $ seems not working easily here,

since we have

$z = [-(x+y^2)/y]$

Then it still needs to consider $z'$ into this equation...

I really really stuck on here.

Is there anyone could help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: It appears to be a Bessel function, specifically $$f_X(x) = K_0(2\sqrt{x})$$ where $K_n(z)$ is a solution to the differential equation $$z^2 y'' + zy' - (z^2+n^2)y = 0.$$

Comment: More specifically, the decaying solution (with a certain constant).